# Golang SAML authentication for Google Apps IdP response

Tags: xml, go, saml

I've used gosaml and go-saml packages from github to build an IdP in revel. Both packages use xmlsec to take the private key to fill in the signed SAML but when trying to authenticate with Google I get the following error: "Google Apps - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request." I've used two different servers, windows and linux to verify that it wasn't an issue with the xmlsec, modified variations of the response from bitium, and okta. Built keys from openSSL and OneLogin test tools. Here is the rendered SAML after being extracted from SAML Trace on Firefox that results in the error:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
            xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
            xmlns:samlsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
            Destination="https://www.google.com/a/wikiplays.org/acs"
            ID="_b521e7bc-9917-4c18-7e89-25032fb49278"
            Version="2.0"
            IssueInstant="2015-10-14T05:42:57.6982498Z"
            InResponseTo="ncgobkpepepgfjhanlpafamijhhpklilagehhfee"
            >
<saml:Issuer>http://104.175.190.209</saml:Issuer>
<samlsig:Signature Id="Signature1">
    <samlsig:SignedInfo>
        <samlsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <samlsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
        <samlsig:Reference URI="#_b521e7bc-9917-4c18-7e89-25032fb49278">
            <samlsig:Transforms>
                <samlsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </samlsig:Transforms>
            <samlsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <samlsig:DigestValue>n9fNsHr4zU9oR6Ycjx1jAdzzb64=</samlsig:DigestValue>
        </samlsig:Reference>
    </samlsig:SignedInfo>
    <samlsig:SignatureValue>YG9ZHBkr5NMm4b5N0NOnasgiLR5U17o9jMTrx6wXtklqx8DxV1uiI7siFRFlsnLy
wk+htqAOhMmTX/pSye6gbIO0xVBNlcRGuMF9uf4CE8dunbQx6cy3nVTKI0MKQtBq
Wpsu6y/v/z/xa+Xg4DDaEprgxi2NwlDOedZ+deUnA54=</samlsig:SignatureValue>
    <samlsig:KeyInfo>
        <samlsig:X509Data>
            <samlsig:X509Certificate>MIICZjCCAc+gAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADBQMQswCQYDVQQ    GEwJ1czET
MBEGA1UECAwKQ0FMSUZPUk5JQTEPMA0GA1UECgwGWmVhbG90MRswGQYDVQQDDBJ6
ZWFsb3RuZXR3b3Jrcy5jb20wHhcNMTUxMDEzMDMyMDAxWhcNMjUxMDEwMDMyMDAx
WjBQMQswCQYDVQQGEwJ1czETMBEGA1UECAwKQ0FMSUZPUk5JQTEPMA0GA1UECgwG
WmVhbG90MRswGQYDVQQDDBJ6ZWFsb3RuZXR3b3Jrcy5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMZJ+2Yg2hg0gBI+O9eglZ5pwvC7CXjaN+R4ZCpOm9w3
82iidvdeWzHxEXpkmEgSPSbot9AO9LhiL0io5vJ9ro6Xh87x/5zuB9IxnFtSAH9S
K4LA4A7lhpA5HrhDUYBIUksqyIc+TBUXA+Blpexs9b5fcjkzN2iVFyBWR2xn17Hl
AgMBAAGjUDBOMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQ7o5RDaoy91nhHgLt8L2YilDlCkjAfBgNVHSME
GDAWgBQ7o5RDaoy91nhHgLt8L2YilDlCkjAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBDQUAA4GBAEFxqDwc2X/cP6YX8neW1AgBxZ4AOAlJ9YgRKQKDuHzOJX22s2ah
65XCA16Tnw8xG0AdZUU5dn07Y05EYgYW+cktvitT9fNTdpJ9JDnGB1KAlVqGlB7d
 oIn8BV7bDA+YkeAgH98UE6OOEkNYnygkg2eT9H0FoyXkMyiizixeH8BO</samlsig:X509Certificate>
        </samlsig:X509Data>
    </samlsig:KeyInfo>
</samlsig:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</samlp:Status>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                ID="_f7437494-03ce-4eb1-483c-169f43f6e1f7"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2015-10-14T05:42:57.6982498Z"
                >
    <saml:Issuer>http://104.175.190.209</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="google.com/a/wikiplays.org"
                     Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:email"
                     >vince@wikiplays.org</saml:NameID>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ncgobkpepepgfjhanlpafamijhhpklilagehhfee"
                                          NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-14T05:47:57.6982498Z"
                                          Recipient="https://www.google.com/a/wikiplays.org/acs"
                                          />
        </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-10-14T05:37:57.6982498Z"
                     NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-14T05:47:57.6982498Z"
                     />
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute Name="Email"
                        FriendlyName="Email Address"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">vince@wikiplays.org</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

Comment: Just checking the obvious first since it's a parse error, is this the *entirety* of the response? Because it doesn't have the outer <?xml> tag or namespace definitions.

Comment: Go-SAML package and the others I've used prepend <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?> but SAML trace the firefox plugin removes it from the displayed output. Sorry, I should have added to avoid confusion.

Comment: But are the namespaces defined? (I'm still assuming this is an XML problem, because I don't know what else that error from google could mean). Does this work with other service providers?

Comment: Yes, I've been using the same namespaces that are defined from two different IdP providers and also the google developers page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation_web?hl=en#samlReferenceImplementationWebCodeStructure

Comment: I will try to use the code against another service provider that takes the same email attribute tonight. At the very least it might give me a better error response. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I was not able to get another SP working completely but it did give a little feedback which said that the cert was not valid.. But it said that even with a verified valid cert that actually logged me in. I'll try a different SP. Also, I ran the Response through a XML XSD schema that I just found on Onelogin here: https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php which threw quite a few errors on the formatting of the xml. I'll fix these before trying anything else even though they do not cause issues with the second SP, they might be bad on Google.

Comment: I've reordered some things in the XML, added the samlsig:reference URI and still get an error from Google: Server Error.